# APK carrying Old data

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I don't even know where to start. This is something I never expected. So I published my app on app store, all works fine but when any user logs in with their username and password instead of loading user's data my app loads the test sqllite data 'I never stored' in my app. Once I go to the app and 'Clear Storage' and ask users to login, then they get the correct data.

It seems like the apk is somehow carrying the sqllite database with test data.

I understand this is not enough information although I am completely confused. On the top the data is not the latest test data.

Is it like my app is packing sqllite with it with data or is it getting dumped somewhere on Google Play store and get attached with everyone's installation? .

Comment: What database did you use?

Comment: Azure mobile services database, it's sqllite

Comment: You should check new user's entered data with the data saved in database. If they are not the same, you should database. Did you do like this?

Comment: User only gets the data as per their user ID, I have all the custom auth and everything setup. Even if it&#39;s a new user, the initial data they see is my test data I saved 3 months ago. Upon clear the app storage data when they log in again, it all works fine...  This led me to a conclusion that some how the apk is carrying the sqllite database with it in which I stored some test data (3 months ago)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This featured named [Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)

> Auto Backup for Apps automatically backs up a user's data from apps that target and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later. Android preserves app data by uploading it to the user's Google Drive—where it's protected by the user's Google Account credentials.

for disabling `AutoBackup`, apply this changes in your application Manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
...
<application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually makes sense. Just a question, shouldn't it save user only data under autobackup and restore when user logs in again, why it is restoring my test data for all the users

Comment: @aliusman You're wrong. It does not restoring test data for all your users, your device and the device google account takes backup of last data on this device. It's not depend on your data and application state, it depends on your device and google account.

Comment: Ok let me have another look into it, that was the first complaint I received from almost all my alpha users that they see test data upon login or creating new account until they clear the app storage data and login again to see empty state

Comment: And the data they see is 3 months old, its not even in live actual database anymore on the server :) this is just crazy

Comment: That's true. This data does not clear by reinstalling or fresh installing or clear data and so on. You just turn it off.